# Active directory login error :A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory, windows-authentication, iis-8

I have an unexpected error while login to the asp.net application through **active directory** (windows authentication)..

I made hard search for this error and i didn't found any thing about SQL server error when connecting as user on domain(active directory)..

The login users i used are users on the domain where the active directory install ?
can any help me..

Notice that the active directory is not installed on the same server that i deploy the app on it..The server i deploy the application through it is joined to the domain where the active directory installed,but they are on separated server and that for some reason..

Comment: Do you have a database for your application? Are you sure it's not complaining about no access to your database?

Comment: Would you provide your web.config authentication settings?

Comment: yeah i have a database accessed by wcf services and i tst it in form authentication and it works normally..so i can access my database and the problem i thought is from web.config..

Comment: also i deploy an empty webform with hello word and it works with active directory

Comment: yeah i provide the web.config setting and test it by deploy hello world webForm...But i cant find where the error comes from?is it from wcf or web.config

Comment: When you debug in Visual Studio, does it break where the exception happens?

Comment: it works on visual studio and on my local windows server..But it bomb when i deployed it in a local network of my customer..And please notice that the conf. of windows authentication are the same in my server and customer server

Comment: The error message should have more information. Does it give you a stack trace that shows you exactly where the exception happens? Or is there any more information in the Windows Event Viewer?

Comment: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server...etc..this is the error that people here asked 100 times for it ..and in  the error there was : unable to connect to the sql database...I dont understand why there is an sql error..i am fuc*ed..in the hall app i dont call any thing from database directly..

Comment: Is there a stack trace that tells you the line where the exception happened?

Comment: No,,but it seems that the problem is the app check the user and call sql server,notice that this server cant access sql server directly ..But i dont know where the app check the user or check the authentication !!

Comment: i solved it..Its from custom membership provider that i used when the app run under form authentication...Thx any way :)